# R calculating mean of a column

Tags: r, mean

I want to calculate mean of a column in R. The column is written in a csv file, namely datafile, as follows.

```
X
12
14
10
...
```

I read the data as follows.

```
myData <- read.csv("datafile.csv")
```

When I want to calculate the mean as `mean(myData)`, I get the following message:

```
[1] NA Warning message: In mean.default(myData) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: It is better to conduct a simple Google search when trying to solve a problem (wonder how long this comment will last <sigh>)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

A good place to start is to read the documentation, for mean with `?mean`.

That said, you are probably looking for the `colMeans` function:

```
colMeans(myData,na.rm=T)
```

The `na.rm=T` doesn't take into account `NA` entries, which is what's likely causing the error.